# using boost thread pool executor submit method

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to learn boost thread pool.
not working, hope to find help here.

Some strange thing happens in the following code, when I

- create an executor `ea` and
- use `async` to start it till it finishes the submitted functions,
- then submit other functions to this first executor `ea` but I don't start it,
- and then go make another executor `ea3` of the same type (`basic_thread_pool`) and different number of threads (1)
- and start the 2nd executor `ea3` with `async`,
- it first executes the 1st executer `ea`, then the second executor `ea3`!

Although I just use `ea3` as argument to `async`.

Why does this happen? and how do I prevent the execution of `ea`?

Does nameless scope has an effect??

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f1b0d190bffd4cf)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_EXECUTORS
#define BOOST_THREAD_USES_LOG_THREAD_ID
#define BOOST_THREAD_QUEUE_DEPRECATE_OLD

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>                        // for lexical_cast
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/caller_context.hpp>               // for BOOST_CONTEXTOF, caller_context_t, operator<<
#include <boost/thread/executors/basic_thread_pool.hpp>  // for basic_thread_pool
#include <boost/thread/executors/executor.hpp>           // for executor
#include <boost/thread/executors/executor_adaptor.hpp>   // for executor_adaptor

#include <iostream> // for operator<<, cout, endl, ..
#include <chrono>   // for operator "" ms, operator "" s
#include <thread>   // for sleep_for
#include <string>
#include <vector>

static boost::mutex stdout_mutex;
template <typename A, typename B = std::string> static inline void trace(A const &a, B const& b = "") {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(stdout_mutex);
    std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
}

static inline void trace(boost::caller_context_t const &ctx) { trace(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(ctx)); }

namespace {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    using std::this_thread::sleep_for;
    void p1() { trace(BOOST_CONTEXTOF); sleep_for(20ms); } 
    void p2() { trace(BOOST_CONTEXTOF); sleep_for(1s); } 
    int  f1() { trace(BOOST_CONTEXTOF); sleep_for(100ms); return 1; } 
}

void submit_some(boost::executor &tp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { tp.submit(p2); }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { tp.submit(p1); }
}

int test_executor_adaptor() {
    trace(BOOST_CONTEXTOF);
    try {
        boost::executor_adaptor<boost::basic_thread_pool> ea(4);
        trace(BOOST_CONTEXTOF);

        submit_some(ea);
        {
            boost::future<int> t1 = boost::async(ea, &f1);
            trace(BOOST_CONTEXTOF);
            trace(" t1= ", t1.get()); // problem unknown on running showing thread result before running code
            std::vector<boost::future<int> > vt1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                vt1.push_back(boost::async(ea, &f1)); // here async starts all closures already submitted to ea
                // then submit f1 to all threads in ea to work
                // asynchronusly so end result will be 7 already submitted
                // and 4 more f1 and return futures to only the last 4 f1
                // which is submitted by async
            }

            for (auto &e : vt1) {
                auto e_value = e.get();
                trace("vt1 e_value = ", e_value);
            }
        }

        submit_some(ea);
        {
            boost::executor_adaptor<boost::basic_thread_pool> ea3(1);
            boost::future<int> t1 = boost::async(ea3, &f1);

            std::vector<boost::future<int> > vt1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                vt1.push_back(
                        boost::async(ea3, &f1)); // here async starts all closures already submitted to ea
                // then submit f1 to all threads in ea to work
                // asynchronusly so end result will be 7 already submitted
                // and 4 more f1 and return futures to only the last 4 f1
                // which is submitted by async
            }

            for (auto &e : vt1) {
                trace("vt1 e_value = ", e.get());
            }
        }
     } 
    catch (std::exception &ex) { trace("ERROR= ", ex.what()); return 1; }
    catch (...)                { trace("UNKNOWN EXCEPTION"); return 2;  } 

    trace(BOOST_CONTEXTOF);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    trace(BOOST_CONTEXTOF);
    return test_executor_adaptor();
}
```

i think that basic_thread_pool use event loop,
and this event loop is singleton,
so when i define another basic_thread_pool it just uses the same event loop,and in turn when getting futures it run all tasks on the event loop including those of other thread pools,
this is a guess but i cant find proof for it from the impl code
in case this guess is right how can i make different event loop for each basic_thread_pool.
i use msvc 14
thanks

Comment: 1. minimal code 2. working code 3. lose the nonsensical locking and tracing. (refer to the comments on previous posts; I'm being nice for not downvoting, but this fully deserves downvotes. You'll want to fix/delete)

Comment: i edited it...i think this behaviour is  related to the hardware actual number of threads and the number of threads i  give as parameter...if the argument "number of threads" is higher than hardware threads then something hidden reuse the thread ...and in this case the pending works on this actual thread are the works of the previous executor so the start executing when i start the new thread pool.....it is a guess but i don't know how to confirm it

Comment: So... Now you've listed the same huge code twice, but the first time with 42 (out of 208) "random" lines of code snipped? Also, the second version includes 139 (!!) empty (comment) lines. [No difference other than that](https://gist.github.com/sehe/6182f6f4cc6d6e7c03e266ceab34e385/revisions). I'm going to try if I can understand this "reduced" code now.

Comment: I've [cleaned up](https://gist.github.com/sehe/071c59280b93941d6b22cd3a61289857) the sample to less than 50% (removing locking issues and unused code). If I have time later this weekend I might look at the resulting question. [Live On Coliru (delays reduced 10x)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f1b0d190bffd4cf)

Comment: i tried your code and it gave the same problem...i think it is the same code :) ...though i don't know about trace() but it seems to be very efficient template......i wonder how u thought of it....thanks a lot for your help and patience

Comment: Yup. Refactoring is improving the code without changing the behaviour. It's important to make the code readable and "obviously correct". Code is _for humans_, not computers.

Comment: boost thread pool has so scarce sources on internet ...i can not get the difference between the adaptor and executor ..and if i can pass class constructor to submit

Comment: @sehe wonder if you found any solution to my problem